# autopopulating child table related by OneToOne in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm pretty new to django, and I'm having trouble with a child table that is an extension of Django's built User model at django.contrib.auth.model.  The child table is UserProfile, and inherits from User.  (see below for my models)

I can't really figure out how to put data in these tables except by the admin site, which clearly isn't good enough.

I'll get my user object and assign it some variable say, `u = User.objects.get(username = 'jane_smith'` then try and reach the data in the child table with the command `up = u.userprofile`.  I'm rewarded with the following error: `DoesNotExist: UserProfile matching query does not exist.`

I experimented getting around the problem by manually inputting data through the terminal, with `up = UserProfile(user_ptr = User.objects.get(username = 'jane_smith'), country = 'USA', num_meals_hosted = 0, cook_rating = 5, image = None, zipcode =91011)` followed by `up.save()`

However, I got the following stack trace

```
>>> up.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 504, in save_base
self.save_base(cls=parent, origin=org, using=using)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 526, in save_base
rows = manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 491, in _update
return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 869, in execute_sql
cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 735, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 34, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '' for key 'username'")
```

Anyone help?  Just want to find a way to put data in these tables through the API.  Below are my models.  Happy to post  more info in comments if needed.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(User):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 15, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True)
    num_meals_hosted = models.IntegerField()
    cook_rating = models.IntegerField()
    diet_restrict = models.CharField(max_length = 600, blank=True)
    blurb = models.CharField(max_length = 10000, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    image_height = models.IntegerField(blank = True)
    image_width = models.IntegerField(blank = True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

Comment: Your title mentions OneToOne relationships, but in fact this is inheritance. Don't use that, use a standard OneToOne.

Comment: @Daniel: Could you please help me understand why?  I had it like that earlier, but it didn't seem to solve the problem either.

Comment: For exactly the reason you show. If you have a standard relationship, you can create the Profile side separately from the User. With inheritance, you can't (without some painful hacking). If you're having problems with OneToOnes, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the needed settings? See:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users